# use "or" in Pyspark for period of time

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a way to include the 3 periods I have in my output? What I'm trying now it's giving me the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

My code:

```
items_bins = (
  fact_pre
  .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
  .filter(f.col('period')==f.concat(f.lit(start),f.lit(' - '),f.lit(end)) or (f.col('period')==f.concat(f.lit(start_1),f.lit(' - '),f.lit(end_1))))
  .withColumn('Sum_Spending', f.round('trx_detail_total_amount', 2))
  .withColumn('Sum_Spending', f.when(f.col('Sum_Spending') >= 6000, 6000).otherwise(f.col('Sum_Spending')))
  .withColumn('Sum_Spending_Bin', f.floor(f.col('Sum_Spending') / 250) * 250)
  .groupby('Sum_Spending_Bin','period')
  .agg(f.countDistinct('customer_id').alias('LP_Identified_Customers'))
)

display(items_bins)
```

I have 3 different periods of time (start,start_1,start_2/end,end_1,end_2). At the beginning the output was only for period 1, then as I thought the code was not reading all 3 periods I tried the "or" part. Thats why I'm getting the error.

Any idea about how to get all the periods in the output?

Desired output:

```
Sum_Spending_Bin        Period                 LP_Identified_Customers
5                  2020-12-01 - 2020-12-31               60
10                 2020-12-01 - 2020-12-31               64
15                 2020-12-01 - 2020-12-31               40
5                  2021-01-01 - 2021-01-31               30
10                 2021-01-01 - 2021-01-31               35
15                 2021-01-01 - 2021-01-31               99
5                  2021-02-01 - 2021-02-28               80
10                 2021-02-01 - 2021-02-28               10
15                 2021-02-01 - 2021-02-28               33
```

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: just replace `or` with `|` as suggested in the error message, and remember to wrap the conditions in parenthesis

Comment: hello @mck, thanks for your advice, I've wraped the conditions and replaced the symbol, now it's working. Huge thanks!